# My app don't initialize on the second time / Geolocation Plugin

Tags: cordova, extjs, plugins, geolocation, touch

I'm having troubles with my app it's made in Sencha Touch 2.3 and Cordova 5.0

Actually, It works fine the first time, after that when you close it, it doesn't work anymore. I updated the cordova from 3.6 and its failing the same.

It's seems to be some kind of trouble with the geolocation plugin, because it stops after the splash screen window and then the screen stays in blank. It's not happening in Android. And it stops searching for the location, showing the arrow icon in the status bar.

If you need to know anything else, please let me know. I'm stuck on this and I really need help. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

some Api not working on some phones.  not working means neither the success nor the fail fires!

for example, I install my app. inside a Samsung Note 2 (Android 4.1.2), the sqlite or the file Api sometimes are not working, but the same code works 100% on Another phone with Android 4.4.2

the work around I use is using a timer in JavaScript to call the Api again when it does not work, but you need to encounter Another problem that if the second call to the Api works, it happens sometimes that the success or fail for the first call comes back, then I have to ignore the result of the first call.

of course, you need to try catch the Api codes!

Anyway, don't assume the app. work or not work, try more phones with different Android version!